# android (phonegap) application opens into a white screen and crashes

Tags: android, cordova

My set-up includes eclipse indigo 3.7.2 with the latest android sdk(updated to lolipop). I've configured this to phonegap 2.9.0. Any application I install into the phone, the application just opens in a blank screen, and nothing else appears. After a while the app crashes. As I use AMD, I'm not able to run the emulator.

//AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.helloworld"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
       android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>

//mainactivity
 package com.example.puremetal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in AndroidManifest.xml change the activity name 
from

```
    android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"
```

to

```
    android:name="com.example.puremetal.MainActivity"
```

Comment: You have identified the issue correctly but, this does not involve a great technical explanation, this could have even been a comment so that the person who questioned could have solved it, just wait to gain more reputation and add comments for the questions which are very silly and which has a typo error